# Use javascript (and jQuery and other libs) from parent document on iframe with several sources

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

good day all.

I'm working on a project in which there is an application that has one of its view implemented with an iframe, the iframe src is changed when the user clicks on some of the "parent" document. So basically there is always the same container, but the contents of the iframe will change according to the user choices.
let's say that there will be:

parent.html (which will have all the js logic)

child1.html

child2.html

...

each "child" page will be an html page with no (or very little) javascript. What I want to obtain is that when the user arrive on the child1.html, only the code that is global to every child is execute and of course also the code related to that page.
Let's say that on the child1.html there must be executed a couple of ajax calls, then some js to handle tables, and things like that. while on the child2.html there will be some forms whith their own validations, and another ajax call to send the forms (displayed on the child1.html).

There will be a big js library on parent.html that will contain the js code of every child page, so what I'd like to have is a way to "know" in which page I am and execute only the portion of code that is related to that page.

the structure should be something like:

```
var myGlobalObject = {username:undefined,foo:1}

if(childpage1.html){
  if (myGlobalObject.username == undefined){
   $.ajax(retrieve username);
   $("#someTableIniFrame",iframeContext).doSomething();
  }
}
if(childpage2.html){
 $("body",iframeContext2).on("submit","#someFormOnChild2", function(){
   //do something
 });
}
```

and/or something on childpages that could execute only its code... like:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //execute only my part of the global js!
});
```

I hope to have been clear on what I'd like to obtain:

a parent page, with all the js used in childs, executed on demand OR with the capability to understand in which page we are.

several child page without or with a very little js.

Just for information, the iframe src will be changed by js on the parent page, by destroying the previous one and adding a new iframe with the new source.

Comment: did you try to add javascript code on the page that you are loading ?

Comment: I'm actually in an assestment phase, I'm trying to figure out how to organize it, since the childs pages will be a lot.

Comment: at this very moment I'm looking on how to "wrap" js functions on the parent, so from child I can only invoke the portion that I need.

Comment: Well since you are trying to be optimal you just have to use the  <script> tag inside the child pages and write the javascript code there

Comment: no, there must be NO or VERY LITTLE js on those pages, this is mandatory.

Comment: You cannot do that without javascript on both the child and parent pages

Comment: You can use "Server-side Includes"  to solve your problem.

Comment: ... or you can use ajax to load the child pages into the parent page

Comment: maybe I'm not been very clear... what I'm trying to achieve is to have NO JS on child pages, but I can have a LITTLE JS on child pages if there is no other way, this means that I can use some js on childpages, but there MUST BE no logic there. just something that "call" the portion of js used there. well... I'll figure out by my self.

Comment: Like I said, you cannot interact with "slave" iframes without adding at least enough javascript to implement the ability to message other pages from different contexts, and then enough javascript to perform your desired logic in the child elements

Comment: You can't just jump contexts from parent to child via iframes as its a security risk (hackers would likely use it to create fake web pages and steal login credentials)

Comment: there will be any security risk cause this will be for internal panels only.
the whole thing will be used only inside a LAN.
I'm actually looking at functions wrappers, so I can wrap several function within a parent one, and call only the parent one from the child page (one line of code in each child and all the logic in the parent page).

Comment: If its within the same origin such as on a single LAN, you can use AJAX (xhr http request)  to load the child pages into an element of the parent page, thus retaining any loaded javascript libraries and making them available to the child pages

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/  and http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: unfortunately, the iframe architecture is also mandatory, is not a architecture of mine, and I must use it.

Comment: You would have to use `window.postMessage()`  and boilerplate code on the child pages.  No way around it.

Comment: yes, I'm also looking in that direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep all the Javascript in the parent page then you just really need a way to map the child pages to any code you wish to execute.  This is a long way around doing something, but without further context it's difficult to suggest a more appropriate solution.

With that in mind, here's how I'd approach your problem.

First of all, I'd create an array of objects that defines what script to run for each child page...

```
var childScripts = [{
    "src": "childpage1.html",
    "init": function() {
        // what to do when childpage1 is loaded
    }
},
{
    "src": "childpage2.html",
    "init": function() {
        // what to do when childpage2 is loaded
    }
}];
```

Don't destroy and recreate the iFrame every time you want to load a new page, or (if you really have to), assign an event handler to the load event every time.  You only have to do this once if you never destroy the iFrame...

```
$("#iframeId").on("load", function() {
    var scriptInfo = childScripts.filter(function(childInfo) {
        return window.location.href.slice(-childInfo.src.length) === childInfo.src;
    });

    for (var i in scriptInfo) {
        scriptInfo[i].init();
    }
});
```

Obviously replace the selector `#iframeId` with something that will find your iframe.

In short, you create an array that holds each child page filename (prefix with `/` so you don't run scripts on pages that end with the same thing, but aren't the same page), and a function that you want to execute when that page loads.  You then parse that array each time the iframe is loaded and execute all associated functions.  Realistically you'll only have 1 init function per child page, but that code will handle multiple instances.

Comment: this looks really nice, I'll dig more in this direction, thanks @Archer

Comment: No problem.  Hopefully it will at least point you in a feasible direction, if not resolve the problem.